# Second part of Eloi's Conjecture

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

We know that "There exist some real k such that ∀ integer n>1 the integer part of k∗nln(n) is always prime?" is false (prove here [Is there a $k$ for which $k\cdot n\ln n$ takes only prime values?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/697644/is-there-a-k-for-which-k-cdot-n-ln-n-takes-only-prime-values?noredirect=1#comment1461399_697644) )
But and if we just consider the odd numbers generated by the function then the same question: Does it exist any k for the same but just consider the odd? (Sorry for my english level)

Answer (score 2):

No, because we can extend the proof to show that there are numbers divisible by 3, 5, etc. In fact, for any choice of $w\in\mathbb{Z}^+,$ there are infinitely many numbers in the generated sequence which are divisible by any given $w$.

Comment: Sure, but you just considered k integer but k is real and how can you prove that those multiples ara not multiples of 2?

Comment: Sorry, variable collision. I can show that, for any real k, that there are infinitely many odd multiples of 3 in the resulting sequence by the same method as in the other thread.

Comment: Show me the prove plis

Comment: Actually the proof on the other thread works, _mutatis mutandis_, for my claim here. The result wasn't stated in greater generality there because it wasn't needed. (In fact, I could give it in greater generality still with the same proof...)

Comment: I want to see the prove

Comment: Show me the prove